# Why can't I log in to SYSTEM without AS SYSDBA

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

When loging in to sqlplus as SYSTEM, why does the login fail with an invalid username/password error if I do not include "AS SYSDBA"

```
C:\Windows\System32>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Dec 16 01:00:13 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn system/password
ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SQL> conn system/password as sysdba
Connected.
SQL>
```

I have a script that I need to run locally.  This script runs fine on other machines, but fails with the error above for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are not logged in as the user SYSTEM. When you execute `conn system/password as sysdba`, Oracle won't even check the user and password (--> from the local system where the db is running). If you enter `system/password as sysdba` and then execute `show user`, you'll notice that you are logged in as the user SYS. So you are actually entering the wrong password when you run `conn system/password`. Oracle does not lie.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba006.htm#ADMIN11046) for more information, because what I told you is not the whole story.